# C++ - Cannot initialize empty string in member initialization list

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++ and i was experimenting a bit with some of its features (mainly templates, pointers, OOP) trying to build a string class, when I got stuck in this problem. The incriminated code looks like this:

string.h

```
...
private:
        char* value;
...
public:
        string();
...
```

string.cpp

```
string::string() : value( '\0' ) {
    std::cout << "Initialized string value: " << this->value << "blablabla" << std::endl;
}
```

What I thought would happen is that the "value" class' memeber got initialized as an empty string as soon as the constructor got called, but apparently I was wrong, since when I call it, I see this on the console:

```
"Initialized string value: "
```

Now, why does the output get kind of truncated once it prints the "value" class member? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: value is not `char`, value is `char *`.

Comment: `'\0'` is not the empty string, it's the null character. The empty string looks like this: `""`.

Comment: `value( '\0' )` is trying to convert the char value 0 to `char*`. You probably meant `value("")`.

Comment: Typo.  A string uses `"` not `'`.  The later is for a character.  Change `'\0'` to `"\0"`.

Comment: One question: why do I have to use double quotes? I thought that a char was identified by single quotes, and value is a pointer to a char

Comment: You can't initialize a `char*` pointer with a single `char` value, it needs to be initialized with a memory address of a `char`.  Using single-quotes declares a single `char`, whereas using double-quotes declares a `const char[]` array, which then decays into a pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code

```
string::string() : value( '\0' )
```

is assigning an integer value of 0, an equivalent of a `nullptr` or just simply `NULL`, to a variable that is meant to be a pointer to the first character in your string.

One thing you can do to make *that particular code* work is to specify an actual string for the initialization:

```
string::string() : value( "" ) // note the double-quotes to denote a string
```

Of course you should also implement the proper handling of that `char* value;` buffer, i.e. make sure you allocate the string when assigning values to it, free the memory when you no longer need it, etc.

**N.B.**
In no way do I advocate for actually doing it this way! I'm only providing an example that would work for this short code snippet. If you were to go with a default value I'd suggest you have a static member variable that you use as your "empty string" initializer. That way, at least, you can check whether your string is empty when you need to either allocate a buffer or free the memory.

In your .h file:

```
private:
    static char empty[];
```

And in your .cpp file:

```
char string::empty[] = {'\0'};

string::string() : value(empty) {...}
```

Comment: One question about when you say that I have to manage the allocation/deallocation of memory: could that be done with a pointer to the actual string characters and a side variable telling me the length of the actual string so that I know how many chars I could read before going outside the correct values?

Comment: It can be any way you make it ;-) What you are suggesting sounds like an implementation using an `std::vector<char>'. Or you can it implemented as a `struct buf{int len = 0; char * str = nullptr;}`. Or something totally different - that is the beauty of writing your own implementation

Comment: `char* string::empty = "";` is ill-formed. `""` is a `const char []`

Comment: @RichardHodges: assigning a string literal to a non-const `char*` is deprecated in C++11 and later, but older versions accept it.  However, for the sake of correctness, it should be this in all versions: `static const char *empty; ... const char* string::empty = "";`

Comment: Or just `char string::empty[] = {'\0'};`? Let me update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are initializing your `char*` with a numeric value of 0, aka `NULL`.  Passing a NULL `char*` pointer to `operator<<` is **undefined behavior**. That is why you are seeing truncated output - `std::cin` is entering a failure state and thus ignores the subsequent `operator<<` calls.

If you want `operator<<` to succeed then you need to change the initialization of your `char*` pointer to a real memory address (even if just to a `nul` character), eg:

```
string::string() : value( "\0" )
```

Or simply (the `\0` is implicit):

```
string::string() : value( "" )
```

Using `"` instead of `'` defines the literal as a `const char[]` array in static memory, and an array decays into a pointer.

Now, passing the `char*` to `operator<<` will have well-defined behavior.

However, if you want your `char*` to be NULL when your string is empty, then you need to take care not to pass the `char*` to `operator<<` if it is NULL, eg:

```
class myString
{
private:
    char* value;
    ...

public:
    myString();
    void print(std::ostream &out) const;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const myString &str);
```

```
myString::mySstring() : value( 0 ) {}

void myString::print(std::ostream &out) const
{
    if (value) out << value;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const myString &str)
{
    str.print(out);
    return out;
}
```

```
myString s;
std::cout << "Initialized string value: " << s << "blablabla" << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you pass `char*` to `operator<<` of `std::cout`, your `char*` will be treated as a C-string, which implies it will be dereferenced.

In your specific case `value` pointer is initialized with `'\0'` - as your compiler might have warned you, it is an implicit way to create a null pointer.

Dereferencing a null pointer is **undefined behavior**, and that explains the abrupt truncation of your output.

Since you need your pointer to be dereferenced, you want to make sure it points to some actual valid memory. That will require proper *memory management* of your class, and that topic will most certainly not fit into one SO answer.

Consider reading some tutorials on [dynamic memory](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/dynamic/) in C++ as a start :)